# Change the title of the second group in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Assume I have a function_3d with three parameters x, y, z . Assume the function is defined as the following:

```
function_3d <- function(x, y, z) {
  return(x + y * 10 + z * 100)
}
```

I am plotting this function using ggplot2 for x in seq(0, 10, 1) while y has a value from c(1, 3, 5, 7) and z has a value from c(2, 4, 6).

Here is my approach:

```
require('ggplot2')
require('dplyr')

function_3d <- function(x, y, z) {
  return(x + y * 10 + z * 100)
}


x_vec <- seq(0, 10, 1)
y_vec <- c(1, 3, 5, 7)
z_vec <- c(2, 4, 6)

allframes <-
  lapply(z_vec, function(inp.z.val) {
    (lapply(y_vec, function(inp.y.val)
    {
      data.frame(
        x = x_vec,
        y = function_3d(x = x_vec,
                        y = inp.y.val,
                        z = inp.z.val),
        group_y = inp.y.val,
        group_z = inp.z.val
      )
    }))
  })

# Bind all the frames
# Note: we can use dply::bind_rows instead of rbind
df.out <- do.call(rbind, do.call(rbind, allframes))

ggplot(df.out,
       aes(
         x = x,
         y = y,
         shape = factor(group_y),
         colour = factor(group_z),
         group = interaction(group_y, group_z)
       )) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=factor(group_y)), alpha = .9, size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "X Label") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Y Label") +
  ggtitle("Plot Title") +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1") +

  labs(aes(colour = "Label of each plot z")) +
  theme(legend.key.width=unit(3, "line"))
```

And the result is:

[image: Plot of function_3d]

Now I have two questions:

1) How can I change the label of y group ( I mean change factor(group_y) text) ?

2) Is there a better way to create this plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drastically simplify the creation of your data.frame by using expand.grid which is made exactly for this situation.

I don't see why you need the interaction of `group_y, group_z` in your ggplot?

What I would have done is the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
function_3d <- function(x, y, z) {
    return(x + y * 10 + z * 100)
}

df.out <- expand.grid(x = seq(0, 10, 1),
                      group_y = c(1, 3, 5, 7),
                      group_z = c(2, 4, 6))

df.out$y <- function_3d(df.out$x, df.out$group_y, df.out$group_z)

ggplot(df.out, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = factor(group_z), linetype = factor(group_y))) +
    xlab("Test label x") +
    ylab("Test label y") +
    ggtitle("testtitle") +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1", name = "color label") +
    scale_linetype_discrete(name = "linetype label")
```

Answer (score 0):

1) At the end add ´+ scale_linetype_discrete(name = 'foo')

2) It seems good ggplot2 to me ^^